# PHP toString() not working

Tags: php, oop, tostring

I am following a udemy course where we learnt toString, however on my browser it displays nothing when I use the toString function.

```
<?php 

class Baddie{

    //property
    public $evilness = 10;
    public $name = "";

    //constructor
    public function __construct($evilness, $name){
        //echo "A ". __CLASS__ . " has been created!";
        $this->evilness = $evilness;
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function __toString(){
        return (string)$this->name;
    }
}

$bad = new Baddie(3, "bob");

//var_dump($bad);

?>
```

Here is a screenshot
Chrome: http://prntscr.com/bl941w

thanks in advance!

Comment: How about `echo $bad;` that the magic function even gets triggered.

Answer (score 3):

You just created a new object `Baddie`, but the `__toString` method is never called. The method only gets called, if you call them directly `$bad->__toString()` or implicit by an cast i.e. `echo $bad;` or `$str = (string) $bad`

In your case, you cast want to use

```
$bad = new Baddie(3, "bob");
echo $bad;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `toString()`

```
echo $bad->__toString()
```

Or just

```
echo $bad
```

If `echo` is called with an object it will search the `__toString` method and use its result as output.